# Select first buyer from each seller each month

Tags: sql, sqlite

[This is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODFk.png)

I have tried the following SQL code:

```
SELECT s.name AS Seller, b.name AS Buyer, created_at AS Month
FROM Relations r
JOIN Sellers s
ON r.sellerID = s.ID
JOIN Buyers b
ON r.buyerID = b.ID
WHERE strftime('%m', created_at) = '08' 
ORDER BY s.name, b.id;
```

The output I got is

```
SELLER  BUYER   MONTH
Maria   Eric    2021-08-01
Maria   Martha  2021-08-09
Nathan  Martha  2021-08-03
Rob     Jill    2021-08-04
```

But expected output is

```
SELLER  BUYER   MONTH
Maria   Eric    2021-08-01
Nathan  Martha  2021-08-03
Rob     Jill    2021-08-04
```

Here are the tables used:

Buyers Table

```
ID  Name
1   Eric
2   Julia
3   Josh
4   Martha
5   Jill
```

Sellers Table

```
ID  Name
1   Nathan
2   Rob
3   Maria
4   Logan
5   Smith
```

Relations Table

```
buyerID  sellerID  created_at
 1        3        2021-08-01
 2        3        2021-07-29
 3        2        2021-07-31
 4        1        2021-08-03
 5        2        2021-08-04
 4        3        2021-08-09
```

Any help would be helpful thanks!

Comment: you have to provide sample data ( raw data in those tables) and an explanation of what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by seller and return the min date.
In this case SQLite picks the row that contains the min date.
Also, you should use `'%Y-%m'` as the format of `strftime()` so that you don't get in the results rows of other years than 2021:

```
SELECT s.name AS Seller, b.name AS Buyer, MIN(created_at) AS Month
FROM Relations r 
JOIN Sellers s ON r.sellerID = s.ID
JOIN Buyers b ON r.buyerID = b.ID
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', created_at) = '2021-08' 
GROUP BY s.ID 
ORDER BY s.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=94a6a021efc662b8bdb7d5b342e45de3).

Comment: @sai fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dense_rank() function to rank your rows and select the first one.

```
    SELECT Seller, Buyer, Month 
    FROM (
            SELECT s.name AS Seller, b.name AS Buyer, created_at AS Month,
                     DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY s.name ORDER BY created_at ASC) 
                     AS row_rank
            FROM Relations r
            JOIN Sellers s
               ON r.sellerID = s.ID
            JOIN Buyers b
               ON r.buyerID = b.ID
             WHERE strftime('%m', created_at) = '08' 
         )T
         WHERE row_rank=1
         ORDER BY Seller
```